# Generating random points with overlapping polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon, sampling

The "Random points inside polygons" tool in QGIS works great to generate a fixed number or density of points within polygons; however, because QGIS does not link the polygon ID to the points, when those polygons overlap, there is no way to distinguish among the points. If you are generating a fixed number of points per polygon, [here is a hack that works](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201357/how-to-create-random-points-in-overlapping-polygons). Unfortunately, if you are generating a density of points in polygons with different areas, this approach does not work as easily. I will simply generate my random points in R from now on, but this seems like a straight forward (and commonly needed) feature. Is there a tool that I am missing?

(I am using QGIS 3.14.16-Pi on Debian Linux and Windows 10)

[image]

Comment: You want to be able to tell which point belong to which polygon? There's the option `'INCLUDE_POLYGON_ATTRIBUTES':True` you are saying that this does not work for overlapping polygons?

Comment: Where is that option? In the GUI tool, there is no field in which to specify any options. Is there a way to get into the command-line version of this?

Comment: Checkbox: https://imgur.com/a/sB2Eno9

Comment: That is not present on my version of QGIS (tool found in "Vector creation/Random points inside polygons". I have edited the original post to include the tool window. Are you using a plugin tool?

Comment: No plugin. You are using the wrong tool. It's called Random points **in** polygons

Comment: I now see the tool you used is available in QGIS 3.16, but it is not there for 3.14.16 (which is the version my students are tied to on the University virtual machines).  Any options for the stable version?